# How to restrict anaconda from upgrading the module being installed if its a higher level dependency

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, anaconda, continuum

I'm trying to use continuum io anaconda packing system to package python-2.7.10 with other dependent modules for our environment. I want to automate the pack distribution to simply be a single installation of python with the modules we require.

The issue I'm having is when I specify the modules under the build parameter in meta.yaml it will upgrade the version of python being installed despite the fact that it is python-2.7.10. This will cause an error in the build process.

Is there a way to pin the version of python being installed so that if there is a dependency it will hard fail, or use an earlier version of the package?

meta.yaml, ive tried not pinning the version of the modules as well.

```
package:
  name: python
  version: 2.7.10

source:
  fn: Python-2.7.10.tgz
  url: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.10/Python-2.7.10.tgz
  md5: d7547558fd673bd9d38e2108c6b42521

build:
  no_link: bin/python

requirements:
  build:
    - bzip2 [unix]
    - zlib [unix]
    - sqlite [unix]
    - readline [unix]
    - tk [unix]
    - openssl [unix]
    - system [linux]
    - ipython 5.0.0
    - numpy 1.11.1
    - cython 0.24.1
    - scipy 0.18.0
    - pandas 0.18.1
    - patsy 0.4.1
    - statsmodels 0.6.1
    - matplotlib 1.5.2
    - ggplot 0.9.4
    - scikit-learn 0.17.1
    - distribute 0.6.45
    - backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.5.0.1
    - certifi 14.05.14
    - nose_parameterized 0.5.0
    - pyparsing 2.1.4
    - python-dateutil 2.5.3
    - pytz 2016.6.1
    - pyzmq 15.3.0
    - simplejson 3.3.3
    - six 1.10.0
    - sympy 1.0
    - tornado 4.4.1
    - virtualenv 13.0.1
    - wsgiref 0.1.2
    - python-swiftclient 2.7.0
    #- python-ceilometerclient #issue
    #- python-heatclient #issue
    #- python-keystoneclient 1.6.0
    #- python-novaclient 2.26.0
    #- python-troveclient #issue
    - python-cinderclient 1.1.2
    - python-glanceclient 0.17.2
    - python-neutronclient 2.4.0
    - networkx 1.11
    - pysal 1.11.1
    - pyyaml 3.11
    - shapely 1.5.13
    - beautifulsoup4 4.4.1
    - nltk 3.2.1
    - requests 2.10.0
    - seaborn 0.5.0
    - h5py 2.6.0
    - xlrd 1.0.0
    - markupsafe 0.23
    - crypto 1.1.0
    - jinja2 2.8
    - openpyxl 2.3.2
    - jaro_winkler 1.0.2
    - bokeh 0.12.1
    - numexpr 2.6.1
    - pytables 3.2.3.1
    - pycurl 7.43.0
    - mgrs 1.1.0
    - psutil 4.3.0
    - biopython 1.67
    - enaml 0.9.8
    - mdp 3.5
    - bitarray 0.8.1
    - clusterpy 0.9.9
    - pyside 1.2.1
    - pyqt 4.11.4
    - parsedatetime 1.4
    - pymysql 0.6.7
    - pyodbc 3.0.10
    - tabulate 0.7.2

  run:
    - zlib [unix]
    - sqlite [unix]
    - readline [unix]
    - tk [unix]
    - openssl [unix]
    - system [linux]

test:
  commands:
    - python -V [unix]
    - 2to3 -h [unix]
    - python-config --help [unix]

about:
  home: http://www.python.org/
  summary: general purpose programming language
  license: PSF
```

The output with the error:

```
$ conda build .
Removing old build environment
BUILD START: python-2.7.10-0
    (actual version deferred until further download or env creation)
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    geos-3.5.0                 |                0        16.9 MB  defaults
    libgcc-4.8.5               |                1         922 KB  r
    pixman-0.32.6              |                0         2.4 MB  defaults
    unixodbc-2.3.4             |                0         688 KB  defaults
    yaml-0.1.6                 |                0         246 KB  defaults
    curl-7.49.0                |                1         543 KB  defaults
    glib-2.43.0                |                2         7.4 MB  r
    hdf5-1.8.17                |                1         1.9 MB  defaults
    atom-0.3.10                |           py27_0         676 KB  defaults
    backports_abc-0.4          |           py27_0           5 KB  defaults
    beautifulsoup4-4.4.1       |           py27_0         116 KB  defaults
    bitarray-0.8.1             |           py27_0          89 KB  defaults
    et_xmlfile-1.0.1           |           py27_0          15 KB  defaults
    future-0.15.2              |           py27_0         616 KB  defaults
    jaro_winkler-1.0.2         |           py27_0          24 KB  auto
    jdcal-1.2                  |           py27_1           9 KB  defaults
    kiwisolver-0.1.3           |           py27_0         571 KB  defaults
    markupsafe-0.23            |           py27_2          31 KB  defaults
    mgrs-1.1.0                 |           py27_0          48 KB  auto
    mpmath-0.19                |           py27_1         873 KB  defaults
    nltk-3.2.1                 |           py27_0         1.7 MB  defaults
    parsedatetime-1.2          |           py27_0          39 KB  auto
    ply-3.8                    |           py27_0          71 KB  defaults
    psutil-4.3.0               |           py27_0         224 KB  defaults
    pycurl-7.43.0              |           py27_0         128 KB  defaults
    pymysql-0.7.6              |           py27_0         116 KB  defaults
    pyodbc-3.0.10              |           py27_0         146 KB  defaults
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py27_4         297 KB  defaults
    pyzmq-15.4.0               |           py27_0         705 KB  defaults
    requests-2.10.0            |           py27_0         611 KB  defaults
    shapely-1.5.16             |           py27_0         494 KB  defaults
    tabulate-0.7.2             |           py27_0          18 KB  auto
    wsgiref-0.1.2              |           py27_0          943 B  auto
    xlrd-1.0.0                 |           py27_0         181 KB  defaults
    biopython-1.67             |      np111py27_0         2.2 MB  defaults
    clusterpy-0.9.9            |           py27_1         101 KB  conda-forge
    cmd2-0.6.7                 |           py27_0          33 KB  auto
    h5py-2.6.0                 |      np111py27_2         2.4 MB  defaults
    jinja2-2.8                 |           py27_1         264 KB  defaults
    jsonschema-2.5.1           |           py27_0          55 KB  defaults
    mdp-3.5                    |           py27_0         477 KB  defaults
    networkx-1.11              |           py27_0         1.1 MB  defaults
    numexpr-2.6.1              |      np111py27_0         347 KB  defaults
    openpyxl-2.3.2             |           py27_0         248 KB  defaults
    rsa-3.4.2                  |           py27_0          50 KB  conda-forge
    singledispatch-3.4.0.3     |           py27_1          17 KB  r
    ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2 |           py27_1           6 KB  defaults
    cliff-1.10.1               |           py27_0          36 KB  gus
    crypto-1.1.0               |           py27_0           3 KB  auto
    pysal-1.11.1               |           py27_0        11.2 MB  defaults
    pytables-3.2.3.1           |      np111py27_0         3.4 MB  defaults
    tornado-4.4.1              |           py27_0         552 KB  defaults
    bokeh-0.12.1               |           py27_0         3.2 MB  defaults
    harfbuzz-0.9.35            |                6         1.1 MB  r
    ipython-5.1.0              |           py27_0         936 KB  defaults
    pyopenssl-16.0.0           |           py27_0          66 KB  defaults
    pango-1.36.8               |                3         796 KB  r
    qt-4.8.7                   |                4        32.7 MB  defaults
    python-neutronclient-2.4.0 |           py27_0         222 KB  gus
    shiboken-1.2.1             |           py27_0         883 KB  defaults
    enaml-0.9.8                |           py27_1         944 KB  defaults
    pyside-1.2.1               |           py27_1         5.7 MB  defaults
    seaborn-0.7.1              |           py27_0         272 KB  defaults
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       107.8 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    atom:                         0.3.10-py27_0       defaults
    babel:                        2.3.3-py27_0        defaults
    backports:                    1.0-py27_0          defaults
    backports.ssl-match-hostname: 3.5.0.1-py27_0      getpantheon
    backports_abc:                0.4-py27_0          defaults
    beautifulsoup4:               4.4.1-py27_0        defaults
    biopython:                    1.67-np111py27_0    defaults
    bitarray:                     0.8.1-py27_0        defaults
    bokeh:                        0.12.1-py27_0       defaults
    brewer2mpl:                   1.4.1-py27_1        conda-forge
    bzip2:                        1.0.6-3             defaults
    cairo:                        1.12.18-6           defaults
    certifi:                      2016.2.28-py27_0    defaults
    cffi:                         1.6.0-py27_0        defaults
    cliff:                        1.10.1-py27_0       gus
    clusterpy:                    0.9.9-py27_1        conda-forge
    cmd2:                         0.6.7-py27_0        auto
    crypto:                       1.1.0-py27_0        auto
    cryptography:                 1.4-py27_0          defaults
    curl:                         7.49.0-1            defaults
    cycler:                       0.10.0-py27_0       defaults
    cython:                       0.24.1-py27_0       defaults
    decorator:                    4.0.10-py27_0       defaults
    distribute:                   0.6.45-py27_1       defaults
    enaml:                        0.9.8-py27_1        defaults
    enum34:                       1.1.6-py27_0        defaults
    et_xmlfile:                   1.0.1-py27_0        defaults
    fontconfig:                   2.11.1-6            defaults
    freetype:                     2.5.5-1             defaults
    functools32:                  3.2.3.2-py27_0      defaults
    future:                       0.15.2-py27_0       defaults
    futures:                      3.0.5-py27_0        defaults
    geos:                         3.5.0-0             defaults
    get_terminal_size:            1.0.0-py27_0        defaults
    ggplot:                       0.11.1-py27_1       conda-forge
    glib:                         2.43.0-2            r
    h5py:                         2.6.0-np111py27_2   defaults
    harfbuzz:                     0.9.35-6            r
    hdf5:                         1.8.17-1            defaults
    idna:                         2.1-py27_0          defaults
    ipaddress:                    1.0.16-py27_0       defaults
    ipython:                      5.1.0-py27_0        defaults
    ipython_genutils:             0.1.0-py27_0        defaults
    iso8601:                      0.1.11-py27_0       defaults
    jaro_winkler:                 1.0.2-py27_0        auto
    jdcal:                        1.2-py27_1          defaults
    jinja2:                       2.8-py27_1          defaults
    jsonpatch:                    1.3-py27_0          auto
    jsonpointer:                  1.2-py27_0          auto
    jsonschema:                   2.5.1-py27_0        defaults
    kiwisolver:                   0.1.3-py27_0        defaults
    libffi:                       3.2.1-0             defaults
    libgcc:                       4.8.5-1             r
    libgfortran:                  3.0.0-1             defaults
    libpng:                       1.6.22-0            defaults
    libsodium:                    1.0.10-0            defaults
    libxml2:                      2.9.2-0             defaults
    markupsafe:                   0.23-py27_2         defaults
    matplotlib:                   1.5.1-np111py27_0   defaults
    mdp:                          3.5-py27_0          defaults
    mgrs:                         1.1.0-py27_0        auto
    mkl:                          11.3.3-0            defaults
    mpmath:                       0.19-py27_1         defaults
    msgpack-python:               0.4.7-py27_0        defaults
    netaddr:                      0.7.18-py27_0       conda-forge
    netifaces:                    0.10.4-py27_0       conda-forge
    networkx:                     1.11-py27_0         defaults
    nltk:                         3.2.1-py27_0        defaults
    nose_parameterized:           0.5.0-py27_0        conda-forge
    numexpr:                      2.6.1-np111py27_0   defaults
    numpy:                        1.11.1-py27_0       defaults
    openpyxl:                     2.3.2-py27_0        defaults
    openssl:                      1.0.2h-1            defaults
    oslo.config:                  1.9.3-py27_0        gus
    oslo.i18n:                    1.5.0-py27_0        gus
    oslo.serialization:           1.4.0-py27_0        gus
    oslo.utils:                   1.4.0-py27_0        gus
    pandas:                       0.18.1-np111py27_0  defaults
    pango:                        1.36.8-3            r
    parsedatetime:                1.2-py27_0          auto
    path.py:                      8.2.1-py27_0        defaults
    pathlib2:                     2.1.0-py27_0        defaults
    patsy:                        0.4.1-py27_0        defaults
    pbr:                          0.11.0-py27_0       defaults
    pexpect:                      4.0.1-py27_0        defaults
    pickleshare:                  0.7.3-py27_0        defaults
    pip:                          8.1.2-py27_0        defaults
    pixman:                       0.32.6-0            defaults
    ply:                          3.8-py27_0          defaults
    prettytable:                  0.7.2-py27_0        conda-forge
    prompt_toolkit:               1.0.3-py27_0        defaults
    psutil:                       4.3.0-py27_0        defaults
    ptyprocess:                   0.5.1-py27_0        defaults
    pyasn1:                       0.1.9-py27_0        defaults
    pycairo:                      1.10.0-py27_0       defaults
    pycparser:                    2.14-py27_1         defaults
    pycurl:                       7.43.0-py27_0       defaults
    pygments:                     2.1.3-py27_0        defaults
    pymysql:                      0.7.6-py27_0        defaults
    pyodbc:                       3.0.10-py27_0       defaults
    pyopenssl:                    16.0.0-py27_0       defaults
    pyparsing:                    2.1.4-py27_0        defaults
    pyqt:                         4.11.4-py27_4       defaults
    pysal:                        1.11.1-py27_0       defaults
    pyside:                       1.2.1-py27_1        defaults
    pytables:                     3.2.3.1-np111py27_0 defaults
    python:                       2.7.12-1            defaults
    python-cinderclient:          1.1.2-py27_0        gus
    python-dateutil:              2.5.3-py27_0        defaults
    python-glanceclient:          0.17.2-py27_0       gus
    python-keystoneclient:        1.3.2-py27_0        gus
    python-neutronclient:         2.4.0-py27_0        gus
    python-swiftclient:           2.7.0-py27_0        chenghlee
    pytz:                         2016.6.1-py27_0     defaults
    pyyaml:                       3.11-py27_4         defaults
    pyzmq:                        15.4.0-py27_0       defaults
    qt:                           4.8.7-4             defaults
    readline:                     6.2-2               defaults
    requests:                     2.10.0-py27_0       defaults
    rsa:                          3.4.2-py27_0        conda-forge
    scikit-learn:                 0.17.1-np111py27_2  defaults
    scipy:                        0.18.0-np111py27_0  defaults
    seaborn:                      0.7.1-py27_0        defaults
    setuptools:                   25.1.6-py27_0       defaults
    shapely:                      1.5.16-py27_0       defaults
    shiboken:                     1.2.1-py27_0        defaults
    simplegeneric:                0.8.1-py27_1        defaults
    simplejson:                   3.8.2-py27_0        defaults
    singledispatch:               3.4.0.3-py27_1      r
    sip:                          4.18-py27_0         defaults
    six:                          1.10.0-py27_0       defaults
    sqlite:                       3.13.0-0            defaults
    ssl_match_hostname:           3.4.0.2-py27_1      defaults
    statsmodels:                  0.6.1-np111py27_1   defaults
    stevedore:                    1.3.0-py27_0        gus
    sympy:                        1.0-py27_0          defaults
    system:                       5.8-2               defaults
    tabulate:                     0.7.2-py27_0        auto
    tk:                           8.5.18-0            defaults
    tornado:                      4.4.1-py27_0        defaults
    traitlets:                    4.2.2-py27_0        defaults
    unixodbc:                     2.3.4-0             defaults
    virtualenv:                   13.0.1-py27_0       defaults
    warlock:                      1.3.0-py27_0        conda-forge
    wcwidth:                      0.1.7-py27_0        defaults
    wheel:                        0.29.0-py27_0       defaults
    wsgiref:                      0.1.2-py27_0        auto
    xlrd:                         1.0.0-py27_0        defaults
    yaml:                         0.1.6-0             defaults
    zeromq:                       4.1.4-0             defaults
    zlib:                         1.2.8-3             defaults

Source cache directory is: /opt/app/anaconda2/conda-bld/src_cache
Found source in cache: Python-2.7.10.tgz
Extracting download
BUILD START: python-2.7.10-0
python is installed as a build dependency. Removing.
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app/anaconda2/bin/conda-build", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 152, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "/opt/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 415, in args_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "/opt/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/main_build.py", line 358, in execute
    debug=args.debug)
  File "/opt/app/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 561, in build
    assert not plan.nothing_to_do(actions), actions
AssertionError: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'op_order': ('RM_FETCHED', 'FETCH', 'RM_EXTRACTED', 'EXTRACT', 'UNLINK', 'LINK', 'SYMLINK_CONDA'), 'PREFIX': '/opt/app/anaconda2/envs/_build_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold'})
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build Python? Do you need a specially compiled version of Python for your use case? If you're just trying to distribute a particular environment to your users, take a look at [`conda env export`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/env/conda-env-export.html) that produces an `environment.yml` file and [`conda create --file`](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason you need to compile python yourself, I think what you're actually going after is `conda bundle` (http://conda.pydata.org/docs/commands/conda-bundle.html).  Unfortunately we've removed it in conda 4.2 which will be coming out soon, intending to move it to conda-build.  Since that hasn't happened yet, and if it ends up actually being useful to people, we can add it back.

---

You could also try this using conda-build...

Remove the whole `source` block in your `meta.yaml` file. Also remove all of the build requirements that are also not run requirements.  Then in your `build.sh` file

```
conda install --yes --quiet \
    python=2.7.10 \
    ipython=5.0.0 \
    numpy=1.11.1 \
    cython=0.24.1 \
    scipy=0.18.0 \
    pandas=0.18.1 \
    patsy=0.4.1 \
    statsmodels=0.6.1 \
    matplotlib=1.5.2 \
    ggplot=0.9.4 \
    scikit-learn=0.17.1 \
    distribute=0.6.45 \
    backports.ssl-match-hostname=3.5.0.1 \
    certifi=14.05.14 \
    nose_parameterized=0.5.0 \
    pyparsing=2.1.4 \
    python-dateutil=2.5.3 \
    pytz=2016.6.1 \
    pyzmq=15.3.0 \
    simplejson=3.3.3 \
    six=1.10.0 \
    sympy=1.0 \
    tornado=4.4.1 \
    virtualenv=13.0.1 \
    wsgiref=0.1.2 \
    python-swiftclient=2.7.0 \
    python-cinderclient=1.1.2 \
    python-glanceclient=0.17.2 \
    python-neutronclient=2.4.0 \
    networkx=1.11 \
    pysal=1.11.1 \
    pyyaml=3.11 \
    shapely=1.5.13 \
    beautifulsoup4=4.4.1 \
    nltk=3.2.1 \
    requests=2.10.0 \
    seaborn=0.5.0 \
    h5py=2.6.0 \
    xlrd=1.0.0 \
    markupsafe=0.23 \
    crypto=1.1.0 \
    jinja2=2.8 \
    openpyxl=2.3.2 \
    jaro_winkler=1.0.2 \
    bokeh=0.12.1 \
    numexpr=2.6.1 \
    pytables=3.2.3.1 \
    pycurl=7.43.0 \
    mgrs=1.1.0 \
    psutil=4.3.0 \
    biopython=1.67 \
    enaml=0.9.8 \
    mdp=3.5 \
    bitarray=0.8.1 \
    clusterpy=0.9.9 \
    pyside=1.2.1 \
    pyqt=4.11.4 \
    parsedatetime=1.4 \
    pymysql=0.6.7 \
    pyodbc=3.0.10 \
    tabulate=0.7.2
```

The big difference: by listing all of those packages as build requirements, you're actually ensuring that they *won't* be in your final conda package.  Think of build requirements more like a compiler, or something that's necessary when you're building the package, but not when you're actually running it.